# Is it permissible to speak with the spouse after engagement?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, men-women

Can one speak with his/her spouse after the engagement has completed? 
Engagement happened as a confirmation of nikah/marriage.

The issue is parents does not like to have the marriage/nikah quickly but they wish to have to at the end of the year even though engagement is done on the beginning of year. So its quiet hard for one party to control eyes so requires the nikah to happen quickly so that at least both partners can have a halal relationship.

Can he secretly consult the girl which he has not yet done and does not want to do because he feels like he is loosing feeling of marriage and being dragged to towards committing zina via eyes?

Comment: http://islamgreatreligion.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/falling-in-love-allowed-in-islam/

Comment: Engagement is not nikah. But if during the engagement nikah was pronounce then there is no harm in talking, seeing etc.

Comment: Was nikah pronounced?

Comment: @BleedingFingers Jazakallah for the reply. No its not and people from girl's side did not want to have it during engagement. thats the issue i'm having right now and seeking for a immediate nikah is also hard as elders of both side wants it to be end of this year. they make inevitable situations and address them as reasons to delay. so as a matter of all these male is feeling bad.

Comment: I would very much appreciate an advice on my issue please. i've tried requesting early nikah but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

An engagement is kind of like a promise to get married in the future and hence your fiancee is not your spouse and does not become your mahram. Hence all the normal rules of male-female interaction will apply (like lowering your gaze, not being alone with them, not flirting or touching etc).

Your fiancee only becomes your mahram when the nikah ceremony is done, with the contract being signed by both the groom and the bride in the presence of the appropriate witnesses.

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/2221

Answer (score 0):

Brother you got bamboozled!  Don't ever commit engagement because most of the parents are searching for earning guys and once they find it, they trap him in engagement until they have vacation or money to throw an extravagant party to bride's people. They don't even know whether the engaged parties love each other or not. They don't trust you and won't let you talk or meet. These are all happening in the name of Islam, Where delaying marriage more than two months is considered as sin/haram. The engagement is invalid then.